# richfaces 4 tool tip

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x

I am having a problem with richfaces 4 tooltip. It is not appearing over text when I hover over it with the mouse. I've been trying to figure out why but I am lost. I am using JBOSS 7.1.1 and JSF 2

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:body>
    <h3>Sample 1</h3>
    <rich:panel style="width:350px">
        <h:outputText id="test" value="Hello World" />
        <rich:tooltip mode="ajax" target="test">
            <h:panelGrid style="width:200px">
                Testing tooltip
            </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:tooltip>
    </rich:panel>
    </h:body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Any console errors or something? What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried using it in Mozilla and Chrome and neither work. Are you using richfaces 4 and JSF 2 as well?

Comment: Yes, RF 4.3.2.Final and JSF 2.1

Comment: hmmm, so weird. It's does not work for me. Did you make any configuration changes or include anything in your web.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Have to copy the whole example next time …)

You're missing `<h:head>` and so the JS for the tooltip isn't being loaded (this should throw an error in the console), it can be empty but it has to be there. You also need `<h:form>` for ajax to work.